# LOOKUP function in Excel is throwing #NA error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using `LOOKUP()` function in Excel. However, it is throwing an `#NA` error. Does excel throw an NA error if the data to be compared is very small?

Here is the data I am checking :

```
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
0.06
0.006
0.6
```

I was using the following command : =`LOOKUP(0.006,F28:F34,G28:G34)` which threw  the `#NA` error.

If I use any other data for instance 0.02 or something, It gives the right answer.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: INDEX/MATCH is more versatile than the VLOOKUP alternative. `=INDEX(G28:G34,MATCH(0.006,F28:F34,0))`

Answer (score 6):

This article on [How to use the LOOKUP function with unsorted data](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181212) recommends three options:

1. `Index + Match` as shown by brettdj `=INDEX(G28:G34,MATCH(0.006,F28:F34,0))`
2. `Offset + Match` like so: `=OFFSET(F27,MATCH(0.006,F28:F33,0),1)`
3. `HLookup` or `Vlookup`. In your context, of those two you would use VLookup() like so: `=VLOOKUP(0.006,F28:G33,2,FALSE)`

Alternately, if you want to use Lookup, do as RocketDonkey indicated and this KB confirms[(How to use Lookup function in Excel)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324986) sort the range first.

As an aside, due to brettdj's comment I did some research. [`HLookup` and `Vlookup` are slightly faster than using `Index + Match`](http://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?132-INDEX-MATCH-versus-VLOOKUP&s=f0c00db6095e44ccdf7dbacdd44f4532&p=566&viewfull=1#post566), but the difference is trivial enough that you should use what you prefer.

Comment: +1 for making the lookup work on Unicode data. I had a case where `Lookup` didn't work on **sorted** array; but INDEX+MATCH solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your values are out of order (`0.006` is less than all of the values there and should therefore be at the beginning). Try resorting your data and seeing if it works since the `lookup_range` parameter of `LOOKUP()` requires that the data be in sorted order.

There may be a reason you aren't using it, but have you considered using `VLOOKUP()`?

Comment: Even if you sort `LOOKUP` may not be apprpriate here because it will give you an approximate match, e.g. sort the data above by lookup range in ascending order and this formula =LOOKUP(0.038,F28:F34,G28:G34) will match 0.038 with 0.3 (it matches with the greatest value <= lookup value) and return G29. If the required result is #N/A (because 0.038 isn't in the lookup range) then VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH should be used as suggested (with range_lookup/match_type set to FALSE/0 to get an exact match)

Comment: @barryhoudini Yeah, totally agree. I was trying to think of situations where `LOOKUP` would be preferable to `INDEX/MATCH` or `V/HLOOKUP' with `range_lookup` set to `TRUE`, but nothing came to mind. Definitely think that `INDEX/MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` is the way to go.